# ServiceWorker Offline - No classNames in HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, service-worker, workbox

I've been trying to implement caching in my React 16 project, using Workbox.
It seems to be caching something, as the page is still being rendered in `offline` mode. But I can't seem to figure out, why my cached version doesn't contain any classNames on the elements.

Normal version:
[image: example with internet connection]

Cached Version
[image: Cached version of website]

Also, the prefetching seems to work correctly too:
[image: prefetching tab]

I've implemented Workbox through Webpack with the following code block:

```
new workboxPlugin({
  globDirectory: 'build/client',
  globPatterns: ['**/*.{html,js,css,png,jpeg}'],
  swDest: './build/client/sw.js',
}),
```

What could be the cause of this? Images are also not being loaded, even though the should be cached too.

EDIT:

It seems like the `.js` files are not being loaded. The `main` & `vendor` `.js` files contain the content required to assign classNames.

[image: .js files can't be found]

As you can see, the `.js` files can't be found. This is in a `preload`, but removing them just transfers the error to the `<script />` including the files. Also the location of the service worker registration doesn't seem to matter.

Side note: My classnames are generated by using `import styles from './index.scss'` `=>` `<div className={styles.container} />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like my SSR (`server.webpack.config`) failed on the CSS loading. I had to modify my server config to match the client config regarding the `css` loader.

Because I didn't have this at first, it would read the `scss` files as a normal `txt` files, which he couldn't recognize, and therefor couldn't use the `styles.container` method.

Putting in proper loaders for the `scss` files fixed the problem.